# Facebook album title export

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Hi I am making a facebook photo album GUI for my website.
Now I already got it woriking in the way that I have my list of albums and can select one and show the photos of it.
But now I have the problem that I cant import the title of the album.
The script I use:

```
    <?php
//Get Albumdata
$naamDataRuw = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$_GET['album_id']);
//Decode data
$naamData = json_decode($naamDataRuw);
//Useable data
foreach ($naamData->data as $data)
{
    //Show description or album name as title DOES NOT WORK
    echo '<h2>'.$data->description.'</h2>';
}
?>
```

Any ideas on how to handle this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does $naamData contain?

Comment: $naamData is the json decoded version of $naamDataRuw

Comment: I know that. What is the value of it

Comment: It gets info from pages like this one: https://graph.facebook.com/413841735419852

Comment: And description is there. Just print `$naamData['description']`

Comment: Could you clarify where and what the code would look like?

Comment: `var_dump($naamData['description']);`

Comment: Could you please tell me where? Because I cant figure out where to put this...

Comment: After you set the variable

Comment: $naamData = json_decode($naamDataRuw);
var_dump($naamData['description']);
?? Makes my page bank out..

Comment: Well then var_dump just `$naamData`, so that you’ll see the actual structure of it.